# When I run :LanguageToolCheck, the output is the java -jar command in a new buffer

Tags: command-line, plugin

I've been trying to utilize Vim to do more writing so I tried to install LanuageTool and a related vim plugin: https://github.com/dpelle/vim-LanguageTool/

However, even after specifying the location of the languagetool_jar (and running :PlugInstall, of course), when I run :LanguageToolCheck, instead of getting the expected Grammar suggestions, I get the java -jar command in a new buffer.

[image]

Comment: Welcome to [vi.se]! This might be better off as an issue on the github repo for the plugin.

Comment: Ok, that makes sense. I was just curious if that might be an indication with how I might have configured my vimrc but I suppose that might come up in the repo too

Comment: If you think that's the issue, you can use [How to debug my vimrc](https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/2003/10604) to trim down your vimrc to a small, reproducible example. This is helpful if you [edit] to include your vimrc, or post it in a GitHub issue.